# Git: how to get a list of all revisions since some commit?

Tags: git

Using rev-list, I've figured out how to get a list of all revisions on one branch since some commit. How can I get a list of all revisions on **all** branches since some commit? Let's say the top of my repository looks like the following. **How can I get a list of all commits since bbbbbbb (commits 3, 4, 5, and 6)?** I don't care about the order.

```
* fffffff 6
* ddddddd 4
| * eeeeeee 5
| * ccccccc 3
|/  
* bbbbbbb 2
* aaaaaaa 1
```

cdhowie's answer is nearly what I need, but it also returns commits from unrelated branches. If I expand the tree to this shape, I don't want to see commit 7 listed.

```
* 0000000 7
| * fffffff 6
| * ddddddd 4
| | * eeeeeee 5
| | * ccccccc 3
| |/  
| * bbbbbbb 2
|/  
* aaaaaaa 1
```

Comment: Ah, well then that's not *"a list of all revisions on **all** branches"*.  Don't ask one question and be surprised when someone answers it exactly.  :P  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
git rev-list ^bbbbbbb branches...
```

For example, on this test repository:

```
chris@zack:~/git-test$ git log --all --graph --oneline
* 8daff2c f      <-- test
* 5f57b15 d
| * 764a725 e    <-- master
| * 5889800 c
|/
* 294908b b
* 975d652 a

chris@zack:~/git-test$ git rev-list ^294908b master test
8daff2c59d8cb966bf399de5027fae85ee016081
5f57b1524afeafbf37984f84fa5fe24ee0ac8501
764a7256d40dbefdb6278443fb80266f00358a37
58898005214607e5c53b45954a98891ea599c037
```

Comment: That actually lists the first commit (and everything earlier)

Comment: @Craig: No it doesn't.  Did you forget to prefix the commit id with `^` like I did in my example?

Comment: Thanks, what does ^ mean here?

Comment: Ah, glad it's working.  And I *just* added an example to my answer to demonstrate that it does work, too.  ;)

Comment: From `man git-rev-parse`, section **SPECIFYING RANGES**: *"To exclude commits reachable from a commit, a prefix ^ notation is used. E.g. ^r1 r2 means commits reachable from r2 but exclude the ones reachable from r1."* "Reachable from a commit" in Git means the commit itself, plus all of its ancestors.

Comment: You can also specify tags instead of commit hashes or branches. To list all the commits between tag `6.1.0` and `6.1.7`, you could say `git rev-list ^6.1.0 6.1.7`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git rev-list` or `git log` (depending on what you're looking for), but the range is the important part.

`git log bbbbbbb..fffffff` in your case will give you everything from `bbbbbbb` to `ffffffff` but not including `bbbbbbb`.  If you want to include `bbbbbbb`, just stick a `^` in front of it.

You don't want *all* changes since that, you want the ones leading to a particular change.  In my repos (where I rebase a *lot*), there's a very large list of endpoints that exist that all fall off on their own.